# Redirect a link to APP or Browser

Tags: php, asp.net, redirect

I have an app (Android App with Webview) composed of just a Webview that shows a web page. When I surf to the App Web Page from the browser, it shows me all of the content exactly like in the App.

Is it possible to redirect the user to download the App from Google Play when he try to enter it from the browser? And what about if he have already the App so it just working without any redirect?

I tried to use User Agent OS, it's working great (It redirects me to Google Play Store), but the problem is when I have already the App installed, and I open the App, it redirects me again to Google play...

Comment: It sounds like your app is completely useless.  Why should it exist?

Comment: thanks for your compliment! it's really useless for peoples like you, but there more than million people that need it. if you don't know how to slove it, you don't must to reply..

Comment: Why do millions of people need a glorified browser?

Comment: "if you don't know how to slove it, you don't must to reply"

Comment: You need to make the app handle a URL scheme.

Comment: You have any tutorial?